# How to count the number of children in firebase when the data is too big?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I typically use

```
var threadnum = 0
ref.child('threads').once('value',(snapshot)=>{
  threadnum = snapshot.numChildren();
  console.log('threads', threadnum);
},(err)=>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

To get the number of threads from firebase but I guess now there are way too many threads so I got `Error: too_big: The data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a single request.`

What do you normally do to get the number of children in such situation?